Stack js some padding between outside border
I would like to add some padding to the border on the outside of my chart, see attached image of expected outcome.

as you can see i have a border width of 1, but its sitting on the chart, i would like it like the above image.


const data = {
  labels: ['onek', 'teo', 'Three'],
  datasets: [{
    data: [1, 3, 9],
    backgroundColor: [],
    borderColor: [],
    hoverOffset: 4
  }]
};

var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
});

jQuery(function($) {
  // Function that formats a raw price amount
  function formatPrice(rawPrice) {
    return rawPrice.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      style: "currency",
      currency: "USD"
    });
  }

  $('form#roi').on('click', '.calculate-roi', function() {
    // update chart 
    chart.data.datasets.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.push({

      data: [mr_results_total, ea_results_total, rav_results_total],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
      ],
        borderColor: ['#CBE1EF','','',''],
  borderWidth: 1,
    });

    Chart.pluginService.register({
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {

        var width = chart.chart.width,
          height = chart.chart.height,
          ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

        ctx.restore();

        ctx.beginPath();
        var fontSize = (height / 114).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.arc(width / 2, height / 2, 80, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#8AC007';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();



        var text = total_number,
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = height / 2;

        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
      }
    });

    chart.update();

  });
});


var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");

// var slider2 = document.getElementById("myRange2");
// var output2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
// output2.innerHTML = slider2.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
#output {
  display: none;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.help-inline {
  display: none;
}

.result {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.roi-success {
  background: #269526;
  color: white;
}

.roi-danger {
  background: #d74e26;
  color: white;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<section <?php theme_section_attr_id() ?>
  <?php theme_section_attr_class( 'pb-5' ) ?>>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col-md-4 pt-5">
        <div class="heading ">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 border">
        <div class="row p-5 pb-0">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <form id="roi">
              <div class="control-group">
                <p>Number <span id="demo"></span></p>
                <div class="slidecontainer">
                  <input id="no_emp" type="range" min="50" max="50000" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
                </div>
                <p>Monthly <span id="demo2"></span></p>
                <div class="slidecontainer">
                  <input id="month_inv" type="range" min="10" max="1000" value="10" class="slider" id="myRange2">
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block calculate-roi">Calculate</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
            <div class="chartbox">
              <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
            </div>
            <p>Estimated Value</p>
            <h3 class="total_number"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>



 chart.data.datasets.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.push({

      data: [mr_results_total, ea_results_total, rav_results_total],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
      ],
      borderColor: ['#CBE1EF','','',''],
      borderWidth: 1,
    });



Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Perhaps use an outline with an outline-offset?

any chance you can demo this @Paulie_D but will try, thank you. am new to chartjs

If this is using chart.js, then the docs give you example how to do it. Adding padding to the layout options. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html

Per my comment, this is the change described in the documentation:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/padding.html
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: data,
  options: {
    // NOTE Added following line to set padding
    layout: {padding:4},
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
  }
});


unfortunately did not work
